# Background image is missing randomly

Tags: css

- Have a look at this code --> http://pastebin.com/RUzy1SSt
- The code above is my simplified version of original.
- The issue I have is sometimes (very randomly) bg.png is missing, that people are not able to see the white background.
- If the background is missing in firefox for example, if people refresh the browser or clear the cache, the background will reappear.
- Any idea?

**Update**
* The 20x20 image background is here --> https://raw.github.com/web-arts-unimelb/unimelb/master/images/bg_white_90.png
* I have added that to the pastin code as well --> http://pastebin.com/59B9snKq
* I didn't post the code here or jsfiddle is format issue, which confused me.

**Update 1**
* I think it is better to have a look at the actual problem --> (link closed)
* and the while background (i.e. a 20x20 pixel image) sometimes is missing.
* Open up firebug and you will notice

```
<div id="backstretch-wrapper" class="col-8"> </div>
```

has no height, but use top and bottom to auto determine the height. I suspect I always need to set the height of 'backstretch-wrapper', so the image knows the dimension to fill.

Comment: please put your code here? or even betterin jsfiddle?

Comment: It there a good reason not to apply a white background colour (`background-color:#fff`) to `.wrapper`?

Comment: ALWAYS post code here.  Even jsFiddle goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the answer might live in using a HTTPS URL the image source. It consumes more resources than using a simple HTTP request. For more information on this see the following link.

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/